# Running commands in bash function as a given user

Tags: bash, openedx

I'm working with the edx open source code base and I'm putting together a dotfile to make it easier to perform various tasks on the server.
I'm having trouble with the following bash function

```
edx-compile_assets() { 
    sudo -H -u edxapp bash
    source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
    cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
    paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
    paver update_assets lms --settings=aws
}
```

When `sudo -H -u edxapp bash` is run, the function halts and nothing happens, when I exit from that env, then the remaining functions execute not as the `edxapp` user, but as a normal user, which causes the commands to fail.

So basically, it looks like `sudo -H -u edxapp bash` starts a separate process, and when that process ends, the remainder of the function executes
I guess what I'm looking for is a `simple` way to run commands as the `edxapp user` which is activated with `sudo -H -u edxapp bash`

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Does `edxapp_env` need to be run in the process that calls `edx-compile_assets`, or can it run in the subprocess started by `sudo`?

Comment: yes, edxapp_env should run in the subprocess as well

Comment: `edx-compile_assets` should probably be a script that you run *with* `sudo`, rather than a function that *calls* `sudo`.

Comment: Also note that you can call single commands as another user with `su edxapp -c some-command`; but @chepner has the right idea.

Comment: Or you could feed the commands on standard input (in a here document,  for instance) to `sudo -H -u edxapp bash`

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `bash` takes a`-c` option, allowing you to invoke `bash` and immediately execute a command/script.  So I'd put the extra statements (source, cd, paver ...) into a script and add `-c myRemainingScript.sh` at the end of your `sudo` line.

Comment: ok, I'll give this a shot. was hoping I wouldn't have to create extra files though, because I've got a bunch of such functions, and creating files to hold commands will be a bit hard

Comment: How about stringing the commands together with semicolons, like `... bash -c "source dirPath ; cd filePath ; paver xxx ; paver yyy " ?